# Can I get my day counted for the Fanatic Badge if i'm logged in from the android app

Tags: support, badges

I'm going to be away from my pc for quite a long time and I'm going to be able to use my phone instead, and I'm a fan of the site.

So as stated above, does my day count if I'm connected through my android app?

Comment: I know for a fact that the mobile website counts days and the full site works well on a large screen phone these days. I don't use the app to know for sure if it does actually count towards days, but I would expect it to be a background task server side that monitors your activity and so not matter if you use the app or website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Does my day count if I'm connected through my android app?

Just being logged in is not enough, you have to perform other activities.

> We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen"
>   and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.
>
> As is true with the sites, we don't actually count all access; only
>   those actions we consider "real". For the mobile app, this basically
>   means accessing the feed doesn't count; we'll probably tweak what we
>   consider "real" over time.

Source [Last seen not updating when using Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/267099), answer by  [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose)